# Pull specific date from analytics.usa.gov API

Tags: python, api

First time having to query an API. Specifically, I am trying to access this API: https://analytics.usa.gov/developer and download from it the .csv report for the "domains" dataset for Thursday, November 22. So far, I have tried executing the following code:

```
response = requests.get(https://api.gsa.gov/analytics/dap/v1/reports/domain/data?api_key=blablabla)
print(response.status_code)
```

And I get the 404 status. 1) Can anyone get around the 404 error? and 2) How do access a specific date for the report?

Comment: If you're getting a 403 error that suggests your key is invalid.  However, I think the site is broken right now; trying to fetch from that report -- even using the `example` link from the docs -- results in `404 Not Found: Requested route ('analytics-reporter-api.app.cloud.gov') does not exist.`.

Comment: I get 404 without the .csv at the end of my url. Is the website not working the only possible explanation?

Comment: Ther must be something wrong with the url you are using.

Comment: Are you able to make it work with a different url?

Comment: Looks like there isn't anything there yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking why an api is returning a 404 error.

Comment: I am also asking how I would pull a specific date.

Comment: _This API is under active development, and breaking changes may be made without warning_

Answer (score 0):

we are actually working *this week* on being able to add a filter for date. Check back in the coming weeks as we implement and alter the documentation. As of this moment, filtering by date is not possible.

as for the 404... we'll look into that today. not sure why that's happening yet.

Comment: If you are part of the support team for the web site, you should state your credentials. It is good that you have provided useful information, but some context would help.